# Compare multiples arrays and merge these when something match - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge, match

I have multiples dynamic arrays (Constructed from the database), for this example I will use the followings 4 arrays:

```
// I have this:

[71] => Array(
        [0] => 72
        [1] => 74
        [3] => 77
    )

[72] => Array(
        [0] => 98
        [1] => 99
        [2] => 195
    )

[74] => Array(
        [0] => 87
        [1] => 88
        [2] => 89
    )

[77] => Array(
        [0] => 96
        [1] => 97
    )
```

And I want something like that:

```
[71] => Array(
        [72] => Array(
                [0] => 98
                [1] => 99
                [2] => 195
            )
        [74] => Array(
                [0] => 87
                [1] => 88
                [2] => 89
            )
        [77] => Array(
                [0] => 96
                [1] => 97
            )
    )
```

I need to merge these array If some key match in other array. I was reading over array_merge() but I can't use achieve.

Help me.

Regards.

Comment: "*I need to merge these array If some key match in other array.*" - What does that mean? How did you get this result? Please add more details to your question (and post what you've tried so far).

Comment: See the example. I have 4 unidimensional arrays and need only 1 multidimensional array.