# Compare and merge arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have multiples arrays and want to merge these, but, merge only when there is a coincidence. Suppose the following example:

```
[82] => Array(
            [0] => 72
            [1] => 85
            [2] => 86
            [3] => 104
            [4] => 218
            [5] => 219
        )

[85] => Array(
            [0] => 194
        )

[72] => Array(
            [0] => 98
            [1] => 99
            [2] => 195
        )

[104] => Array(
        [0] => 105
    )
```

And I need this:

```
[82] => Array(

        [72] => Array(
                    [0] => 98
                    [1] => 99
                    [2] => 195
                )
        [85] => Array(
                    [0] => 194
                )
        [2] => 86
        [104] => Array(
                    [0] => 105
                )
        [4] => 218
        [5] => 219
)
```

I had 4 unidimensional arrays and now, I have only 1 multidimensioal array.

How can I do something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare multiples arrays and merge these when something match - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563547/compare-multiples-arrays-and-merge-these-when-something-match-php)

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a simple function for your needs. Notice the reference in the function & foreach loop which are really helpful here. This will merge the array in your wanted style, but will merge it every time (means 1 array can go to more than one array). If you want to remove the array which is added, take a look on the end of the post.

```
function merge_myway($array, &$depth) {
    foreach($depth as $key => &$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
            merge_myway($array, $value);
        else
        {
            if(array_key_exists($value, $array))
            {
                $value = array($value => $array[$value]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$array = [
        82 => array(
            0 => 72,
            1 => 85,
            2 => 86,
            3 => 104,
            4 => 218,
            5 => 219,
        ), 
        85 => array(
            0 => 194,
        ), 
        72 => array(
            0 => 98,
            1 => 99,
            2 => 195,
        ), 
        104 => array(
            0 => 105,
        ),
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
merge_myway($array, $array);
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Function with destroying the array after the merging:

```
function merge_myway(&$array, &$depth) {
    foreach($depth as $key => &$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
            merge_myway($array, $value);
        else
        {
            if(array_key_exists($value, $array))
            {
                $temp = $array[$value];
                unset($array[$value]);
                $value = array($value => $temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```